# SQL Server Bulk Insert File Does Not Exist

Tags: sql-server

```
create table StudentInfo
(
Name nvarchar(100) ,
AdminNo nvarchar(10) ,
Gender char(1) ,
BirthDate datetime ,
BGRStatus nvarchar(10) ,
)


bulk insert StudentInfo from 'C:\Users\Tracy\Desktop\StudentInfo\StudentInfo.txt'
```

after execute, the message given is 'Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 34
Cannot bulk load. The file "C:\Users\Tracy\Desktop\StudentInfo\StudentInfo.txt" does not exist.'

but the file is clearly there

Comment: Client side vs server side. File has to be accessible from SQL Server instance not your local computer. From [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): **`data_file must specify a valid path from the server on which SQL Server is running.`**

Comment: your C:\Users\[etc.] is not the same as the SQL Server's one (except we are talking about a _LOCAL INSTALLATION_). You must put your file into some path that can be reached by sql server.

Comment: thanks, figured it out!

Comment: If you want to load data from client, you might to use [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017) instead. It's the client tool for bulk loading data.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue a couple months back.  As Lukasz stated, the file has to be accessible from SQL Server instance not your local computer.

Essentially...

```
The UNC path must be visible to the remote SQL Server instance.

    The account that SQL Server runs as must be a domain account with network privileges and rights to the remote file.
```

I came up with the following approach for loading data to SQL Server.

```
#1)  Convert your TXT file to XLSB (or XLSM).

#2)  Run the VBA script below.



Sub TestExportToSQLServer()
    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim ServerName As String
    Dim DatabaseName As String
    Dim TableName As String
    Dim UserID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim RowCounter As Long
    Dim NoOfFields As Integer
    Dim StartRow As Long
    Dim EndRow As Long
    Dim ColCounter As Integer

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ServerName = "server_name" ' Enter your server name here
    DatabaseName = "db_name" ' Enter your  database name here
    TableName = "customer_master" ' Enter your Table name here
    UserID = "" ' Enter your user ID here
    ' (Leave ID and Password blank if using windows Authentification")
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    NoOfFields = 331 ' Enter number of fields to update (eg. columns in your worksheet)
    StartRow = 2 ' Enter row in sheet to start reading  records
    EndRow = 106695 ' Enter row of last record in sheet

     '  CHANGES
    Dim shtSheetToWork As Worksheet
    Set shtSheetToWork = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("customer_master")
     '********

    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & ServerName & ";Database=" & DatabaseName & _
    ";Uid=" & UserID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

    rs.Open TableName, Cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

     'EndRow = shtSheetToWork.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For RowCounter = StartRow To EndRow
        rs.AddNew
        For ColCounter = 1 To NoOfFields
        'On Error Resume Next
            rs(ColCounter - 1) = shtSheetToWork.Cells(RowCounter, ColCounter)
        Next ColCounter
        Debug.Print RowCounter
    Next RowCounter
    rs.UpdateBatch

     ' Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Set a reference to `Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.8 Library`